# My Javascript code is coming back as null and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript

Been looking through my text book to try and figure out what I did wrong, but so far I've found nothing ( this is a Javascript unit in a HTML/CSS book.) I've tried commenting out everything except for the new Date(); line but that is not appearing on the HTML page. I've made absolutely sure that the files are in the same folder,  and the javascript file does appear in developer tools with the HTML but when I load the HTML page, the HTML shows up but in place of the Javascript on the page it just says null.. Can someone with more experience in Javascript be able to point out what's making the code return null? Everything is global because the assignment did not ask for functions, should I put this in a function?

The code is supposed to display today's date, then according to that date, display a map according to what day and time it is in the year.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
var thisTime = new Date();
var thisStr = thisTime.toLocaleString();
document.getElementById("timeStamp").innerhtml = thisStr;
var thisHour = thisTime.getHours();
var thisMonth = thisTime.getMonth();
var mapNum = (thisMonth * 2 + thisHour) % 24;
var imgStr = document.getElementById("<img src= 'sd_sky'+ mapNum + '.png'></img>'");
```

document.getElementById("planisphere").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', imgStr);

EDIT: Thanks to you guys I was able to fix my code by capitalizing the HTML in innerHTML and use this for defining my imgStr and getting it to display the correct image:

```
var imgStr = document.createElement("img");
imgStr.src =('sd_sky' + mapNum + '.png');
document.getElementById("planisphere").appendChild(imgStr);
```

HTML

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Star Dust Stories: Using a Planisphere</title>
   <link href="sd_base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="sd_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="sd_mapper.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
   <header>
      <nav class="horizontal">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Astronomers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Moons</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Planets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stars</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Physics</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <img src="sd_logo.png" alt="SkyWeb" />
   </header>
   <section id="left">
      <article>
         <h1>The Planisphere</h1>
         <p>A <strong>planisphere</strong> is a visual aid to astronomers and stargazers. 
            It consists of two disks: One displays all of the visible 
            constellations in the night sky, and the other covers the first 
            and contains a window that indicates the portion of the sky currently 
            visible. The second disk is then rotated to match the current date and 
            time. Planispheres come in a variety of sizes and types. The important 
            thing to remember is that you must have a planisphere that matches 
            the longitude of your stargazing location.
         </p>
         <p>On the right is an online planisphere. It consists of two images laid on
            top of one another. The top image is the viewing disk of the planisphere. The
            bottom image contains the sky map. This planisphere is 
            automatically rotated for you, displaying the current date and time 
            and visible constellations for observers at a longitude of 
            40<sup>&deg;</sup> North. To use a planisphere, hold directly overhead with
            the arrow facing north as indicated on the viewing disk.</p>
      </article>
   </section>
   <section id="right">
      <div id="planisphere">   
         <img id="mask" src="sd_mask.png" alt="" />      
         <div id="timeStamp">March 1, 2018 4:53 PM</div>
         <img src= "sd_sky"></img>
      </div> 
   </section>
   <footer>
      Star Dust Stories &copy; 2018 English (US) <span><a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Developers</a> <a href="#">Privacy</a> 
      <a href="#">Terms</a> <a href="#">Help</a></span>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `innerhtml` => `innerHTML`, and what exactly do you expect `document.getElementById("<img src= 'sd_sky'+ mapNum + '.png'></img>'");` to do?

Comment: I don't see code that returns *anything*.

Comment: `var imgStr = '<img src="sd_sky" + mapNum + ".png"></img>';`

Comment: @TJ_Crowder Ahh whoops, so that line you asked about is supposed to display one of the pictures in the folder like if map number is 2 display sd_sky2.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the line:

```
    var imgStr = document.getElementById("<img src= 'sd_sky'+ mapNum + '.png'></img>'");
```

The function getElementByID expects the id of the element you want to retrieve, what you have is the HTML for an image tag.

Assuming you have this HTML in your document, replace the HTML with just "id_sky"

```
var thisTime = new Date();
var thisStr = thisTime.toLocaleString();
document.getElementById("timeStamp").innerHTML = thisStr;
var thisHour = thisTime.getHours();
var thisMonth = thisTime.getMonth();
var mapNum = (thisMonth * 2 + thisHour) % 24;
var imgStr = document.getElementById("sd_sky");
document.getElementById("planisphere").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', imgStr);
```

HTML

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Star Dust Stories: Using a Planisphere</title>
   <link href="sd_base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="sd_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="sd_mapper.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
   <header>
      <nav class="horizontal">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Astronomers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Moons</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Planets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stars</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Physics</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <img src="sd_logo.png" alt="SkyWeb" />
   </header>
   <section id="left">
      <article>
         <h1>The Planisphere</h1>
         <p>A <strong>planisphere</strong> is a visual aid to astronomers and stargazers. 
            It consists of two disks: One displays all of the visible 
            constellations in the night sky, and the other covers the first 
            and contains a window that indicates the portion of the sky currently 
            visible. The second disk is then rotated to match the current date and 
            time. Planispheres come in a variety of sizes and types. The important 
            thing to remember is that you must have a planisphere that matches 
            the longitude of your stargazing location.
         </p>
         <p>On the right is an online planisphere. It consists of two images laid on
            top of one another. The top image is the viewing disk of the planisphere. The
            bottom image contains the sky map. This planisphere is 
            automatically rotated for you, displaying the current date and time 
            and visible constellations for observers at a longitude of 
            40<sup>&deg;</sup> North. To use a planisphere, hold directly overhead with
            the arrow facing north as indicated on the viewing disk.</p>
      </article>
   </section>
   <section id="right">
      <div id="planisphere">   
         <img id="mask" src="sd_mask.png" alt="" />      
         <div id="timeStamp">March 1, 2018 4:53 PM</div>
         <img src= "sd_sky"></img>
      </div> 
   </section>
   <footer>
      Star Dust Stories &copy; 2018 English (US) <span><a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Developers</a> <a href="#">Privacy</a> 
      <a href="#">Terms</a> <a href="#">Help</a></span>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is all of the Javascript, the image still does not appear. I put this in my HTML
<img src= "sd_sky"></img>
Will post my HTML in the question now.

Comment: Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp for help, you will need to use document.createElement to create the HTML with the sd_sky id + your mapNum, then append it to your document.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this, where do I put the mapNum here though?

Comment: The only way you can do that is to add the image element with the id you require to the document using the "createElement" function I posted earlier, then you need to append the HTML to your document.

Comment: Thank you so much! I studi=ed it and looked at some videos and references for it and I got the page to work! I will edit my post with the correct code! (Sorry for  the late reply, I had to take care of my nephews.